# NodeJS promises: Do I have a race condition problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some code which runs on an event happening, and calls a CPU intensive method which finds and creates a lock/hold on an available area of information, it then locks this space

In order to make this non blocking the CPU intensive method is run asynchronously by having it return a promise, then the promise .then code block sets that area as locked using lockSelectedSpace.

```
function eventCode(params){
  findFreeSpace(params).then((details)=>{
     lockSelectedSpace(details);
  });  
}

function findFreeSpace(details){
   //cpu itensive operation here
   resolve({success:true});
} 

function lockSelectedSpace(details){
  // lock the free space
}
```

My question is, when will lockSelectedSpace run?, does it run immediately when findFreeSpace invokes resolve?, or is there a delay?

I ask because it is important that lockSelectedSpace runs on the findFreeSpace and it is not possible for two users to lock the same space

Thank you

Comment: It seems to me that Promise.all() may help in this situation.

Comment: Returning a promise doesn't suddenly make a CPU intensive task asynchronous. Are you actually doing something asynchronous in this CPU intensive task? Or just wrapping up the result in a promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lockSelectedSpace` will run as soon as `findFreeSpace` resolves the promise successfully. When you place this function inside of the `.then` function you are explicityly waiting for the promise to resolve before running `lockSelectedSpace`. Can you provide an example of what you think to be a race condition?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once the promise resolves it will execute the functions registered via `then`. From the MDN Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promis

> A pending promise can either be fulfilled with a value, or rejected with a reason (error). When either of these options happens, the associated handlers queued up by a promise's then method are called. (If the promise has already been fulfilled or rejected when a corresponding handler is attached, the handler will be called, so there is no race condition between an asynchronous operation completing and its handlers being attached.)

Answer (score 0):

If find free space function is blocking type, then all the findFreeSpace tasks will run before, then all the lockSelectedSpace.

JavaScript is a single-threaded environment, in a single-threaded environment, only one section of code can be running at any one time, so, don't worry.

```
let find = 0
let lock = 0

function findFreeSpace(i){
    //cpu intensive operation here
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        find = find +1
        console.log("[find, lock, i]:",find, lock, i)
        const interactions = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1)
        for(let x = 0; x<= interactions; x++){}
        find = find -1
        resolve(i)
    })
}
function lockSelectedSpace(i){
    lock = lock +1
    console.log("[find, lock, i]:",find, lock, i)
    lock = lock -1
}

function eventCode(i){
    findFreeSpace(i).then((i)=>{
        lockSelectedSpace(i)
    })
}

for(let i =0; i< 100; i++){
    eventCode(i)
}
```